# step-by-step guide slim-lang installation into my editor

Tags: html, slim-lang

I like to try to use slim in my new project,however I am unsure of how to make slim 'appear' in my notepad ++.After a search , I found that there is a template in github. However I do not know how to install slim as a gem.I got stuck with this code.

`gem install slim`.

Comment: this is where I found the template :https://github.com/slim-template/slim

Comment: Do you have ruby installed?

Comment: I do not have ruby installed

Comment: `gem` is dependent on Ruby.